# what are the implications of referencing (org.eclipse.ui.internal) types defined inside jar files with "Discouraged Access" rules?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, jar

When I try to programmatically display an html file on a web browser within eclipse by opening the IViewPart with id = rg.eclipse.ui.internal.browser.WebBrowserView.WEB_BROWSER_VIEW_ID, eclipse displays a "discouraged access" marker on my code.

> Discouraged access: The type WebBrowserView is not accessible due to
>   restriction on required library
>   C:\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.ui.browser_3.4.2.v20130123-162658.jar

The code still compiles and the plugin runs properly, but I need to know what are the implications of referencing types whose access is discouraged.

By using those types, am I diminishing the number of eclipse clients on which my plugin can run properly? Or am I just running the risk that at some point in the future my code will break?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things I could think of:

- your code possibly would break if that library gets updated
- the library is meant to be used by internal eclipse process, not for public usage
- the license of the component doesn't allow you to "redistribute" it

Comment: These are all correct statements, but in my experience, using internal APIs during Eclipse plugin development is inescapable for any realistic plugin. Sp, in general, I use these warnings as guidelines, but tend to ignore them.